# Trouble extracting data from 2D array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have used Ajax to run a PHP script to return records in a database. I have managed to retrieve the 2D array into my JavaScript file on the success of the Ajax call. I then call a function.

In the function I would like to pull the data from the arrays and save them into JavaScript variables.

I am using jQuery, so I assume I have to use `$.each`?

Here is the response I am receiving back from the ajax call:

```
[{"level":"1","location":"4554","quantity":"2","game_item_id":"1"},{"level":"1","location":"4554","quantity":"1","game_item_id":"5"}]
```

What I am trying to do is extract the level, location data from this 2D array and save it into level and location variables in JavaScript.

Also as you can see the two records being sent back are identical except the `game_item_id` and the `quantity`. I want to save a list of the `game_item_id`s and their associated `quantity` values into an array or variable.

**EDIT**
Thanks to answers i have managed to save the level and location data into variables. But im still stumped on how to store each game item id and the quantity of each?

Comment: `data[0].location`, if it's parsed into an object, otherwise you'll need JSON.parse.

Answer (score 0):

what about this ;

```
data[1].level
```

You can loop through each array like this

```
data = $.parseJSON(data); // if data is not in json
$.each(data, function(item, value) {
   alert(value.level);
   alert(value.location);
   alert(value.game_item_id);
   alert(value.quantity);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

say your object is named `data`...use loop

```
$.each(data,function(i,v){
   console.log(v.level);
   console.log(v.location);
 })
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm for the level and location data, what would you suggest i do for the game_item_id and quantity scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi refer below code to get id and quantity in array ::

```
var list =
[{"level":"1","location":"4554","quantity":"2","game_item_id":"1"},{"level":"1","location":"4554","quantity":"1","game_item_id":"5"}];

var arrGameIdAndQuantity = new Object();

for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){    
    id = list[i]["game_item_id"];
    qty = list[i]["quantity"];    
    arrGameIdAndQuantity[id] = qty;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(arrGameIdAndQuantity))
```